# Vaadin AbstractClientConnector::detach fires twice

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I have Vaadin 7 application. When I open some popup window and leave application idle for 30-40 minutes I got NPE when closing this window. Here the relevant trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.detach(AbstractClientConnector.java:603) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.detach(AbstractClientConnector.java:598) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.detach(AbstractComponent.java:589) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.detach(AbstractClientConnector.java:598) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.detach(AbstractComponent.java:589) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.detach(AbstractClientConnector.java:598) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.detach(AbstractComponent.java:589) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.detach(AbstractClientConnector.java:598) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.detach(AbstractComponent.java:589) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.AbstractComponent.setParent(AbstractComponent.java:471) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.Window.setParent(Window.java:153) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.UI.removeWindow(UI.java:514) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.Window.close(Window.java:244) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.ui.Window.changeVariables(Window.java:206) ~[vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:396) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleBurst(ServerRpcHandler.java:221) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:111) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:91) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:37) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1382) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:238) [vaadin-server-7.1.10.jar:7.1.10]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727) [servlet-api.jar:na]
```

As can be seen AbstractClientConnector.detach fires twice and I got NPE on getUI() method call. What can be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: since your version is 7.1 and 7.6 is around the corner, have you tried with a newer version, where this might have been fixed already?

Comment: I will try it and update on result

Comment: @cfrick I've updated to 5.7.9 but according to source code there still NPE possible due to implementation of AbstractClientConnector::getUI(). I will try to reproduce the problem again

Comment: then you might be better served by filing a bug with the vendor

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be bug in Vaadin
https://dev.vaadin.com/ticket/19240

Bug is still unresolved so it might be a real issue